# What should I do? A multisite, a single website or many websites?

Tags: multisite, migration, blog, customization, wiki

I'm working on a big website project, we have some time allowed to redo the website first.

Currently, it's a multisite with 2 working sites, one is the landing page and the main content, the other is the blog. I've got 2 other hidden sites, one is a wiki which is not ready, one is my working space (right now I'm planing on fusing them all), I also have many dead project hidden behind.

Am I using the multisite properly? If I do, how can I scale my website effectively? If I don't, is it better to split them into many different website, or a single huge website?

This is a work-in-progress, a lot more is going to be added in the future.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a correct answer here, if it works it works, my recommendation is to merge the blog and main content, but they may have wildly different themes, or be separate for other reasons not shared here. This seems to be looking for reassurance rather than something that can be marked as accepted

Comment: maybe I am looking for assurance, ahah, the theme is also a question we have within the team, but we mainly focus on the long term of the website and how much it's gonna be different if we add a lot of content

Answer (score 0):

You can have a different theme for each sub-site in multisite. Just set up the subsite, then select the theme from the available ones. If the sites are related to each other in some way, then having a common domain name might be an advantage (although there are some redirect things you can do to fix that).

Based on the limited information you provided, I'd go with a multisite. Add lots of available themes as needed to the main site, then select the theme you want to use for each sub-site.

Note that multisites will create 8-10 tables in your database for each sub-site, so make sure your hosting place will support that. Some hosting places will want you to use a premium plan for lots of tables in a database, rather than their base/cheapest plan.